# Oracle SQL Challenging question – Seems impossible to find minimum of value based on other table colmn

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below mentioned data in Table Report-A and Report B.

REPORT-A

```
************************************************
Caseno  Followup Date       REPORT_VERSIOn
***************************************************
C1    26-JAN-22 20:17:54    7
C1    21-FEB-22 18:43:31    8
C1    21-FEB-22 18:44:37    9
C1    21-MAR-22 20:44:37    10
C1    22-MAR-22 17:56:59    11
C1   22-MAR-22 18:45:18     12
C1    24-MAR-22 00:51:12    13
```

REPORT-B

```
************************************************
Caseno  Sub Date        REPORT_VERSIOn
***************************************************
C1     27-JAN-22 00:00:00   7
C1     24-FEB-22 00:00:00   9
C1     24-MAR-22 00:00:00   13
```

Now we want find the followup_Date from table REPORT-A , Based on Table REPORT-B where if
REPORT-B.VERSION >=REPORT-A.version and REPORT-B.Sub-Date >=REPORT-A. Followup Date then find the minimum of REPORT-A. Followup Date.

Means Final Data should be like :-

REPORT-A JOIN REPORT B by common column Caseno.

```
*************************************************************************************************
A.Caseno   B.Sub Date       B.REPORT_VERSIOn   A.REPORT_VERSIOn        A.Followup_Date
**************************************************************************************************
C1         27-JAN-22 00:00:00      7           7                       26-JAN-22 20:17:54
C1         24-FEB-22 00:00:00      9           8                       21-FEB-22 18:43:31
C1         24-MAR-22 00:00:00      13          10                      21-MAR-22 20:44:37
```

Comment: Why does your report B version 9 join to version 8 of report A, and not version 7? What are the rules determining what the "minimum of report A followup date" actually means?

Comment: Thanks and Report -A has the information about Follow-up date and Report B has information about Submission date so we can have many followup in case before it submit to system.

Comment: Thanks and Report -A has the information about Follow-up date and Report B has information about Submission date so we can have many followup in case before it submit to system. Now we need to find the minimum last follow-up version and followup date before it submit to system. Here Report B version submitted version 7 match with followup version 7 because its only the minimum it. Report-B version 9 (submitted) version has two followup version 8, 9 in Report-A but min(8,9)=8 so took he version 8 from Report-A table. Report-B version 13(submitted) has Followup Report version min(10,11,12,13)=13

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can find the previous version for `report_b` using the `LAG` analytic function and then use a `LATERAL` join to find the matching rows in `report_a` that are between the previous and current version for each row in `report_b` and use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to get the minimum of those `report_a` rows:

```sql
SELECT a.caseno,
       b.sub_date,
       b.report_version AS b_report_version,
       a.followup_date,
       a.report_version AS a_report_version
FROM   ( SELECT b.*,
                LAG(report_version, 1, report_version - 1)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY caseno ORDER BY report_version)
                  AS prev_version
         FROM   report_b b
       ) b
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   report_a a
         WHERE  a.caseno = b.caseno
         AND    a.report_version <= b.report_version
         AND    a.report_version >  b.prev_version
         ORDER BY followup_date ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) a
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE REPORT_A (Caseno, Followup_Date, REPORT_VERSION) AS
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-01-26' + INTERVAL '20:17:54' HOUR TO SECOND,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-02-21' + INTERVAL '18:43:31' HOUR TO SECOND,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-02-21' + INTERVAL '18:44:37' HOUR TO SECOND,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-03-21' + INTERVAL '20:44:37' HOUR TO SECOND, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-03-22' + INTERVAL '17:56:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-03-22' + INTERVAL '18:45:18' HOUR TO SECOND, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-03-24' + INTERVAL '00:51:12' HOUR TO SECOND, 13 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE REPORT_B (Caseno, Sub_Date, REPORT_VERSION) AS
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-01-27' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-02-24' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', DATE '2022-03-24' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 13 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CASENO | SUB_DATE | B_REPORT_VERSION | FOLLOWUP_DATE | A_REPORT_VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 2022-01-27 00:00:00 | 7 | 2022-01-26 20:17:54 | 7 |
| C1 | 2022-02-24 00:00:00 | 9 | 2022-02-21 18:43:31 | 8 |
| C1 | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 | 13 | 2022-03-21 20:44:37 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TkuHRo5a)

Comment: Thansk a lot and seems like its very very good solution. Let me try now.